# Flutter: Firebase Analytics not compatible with null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, nullable, firebase-analytics

I tried to move my project to the new Dart and make it null safety compatible but seems firebase_analytics is still not ready.
How can I bypass this error, are they going to release firebase_analytics null safety soon?
I filed an issue here: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/discussions/5108

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^0.8.0-1.0.nullsafety.2
  firebase_messaging: ^9.0.0-1.0.nullsafety.1
  firebase_analytics: ^7.0.1
  firebase_crashlytics: ^0.5.0-1.0.nullsafety.3
```

When I compile I get this error :

```
Because firebase_analytics >=7.0.1 depends on firebase_core ^0.7.0 and ketab depends on firebase_core ^0.8.0-1.0.nullsafety.2, firebase_analytics >=7.0.1 is forbidden.
So, because yourapp depends on firebase_analytics ^7.0.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because yourapp depends on firebase_analytics ^7.0.1, version solving failed.)
```

Answer (score 1):

FlutterFire by the moment dont have null safety coverage for all of their packages

1 You can fork flutter fire repo https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire
then you can play with versions in pubspec of firebase_analytics
then just use own version like that

```
firebase_analytics:
    git:
      url: HERE_YOUR_FORKED_REPO_URL
      path: packages/firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics
```

2 I had familiar problem recently, just removed version at all and now its worked for me))

```
firebase_auth: ^0.21.0-1.0.nullsafety.0
cloud_firestore: 0.17.0-1.0.nullsafety.2
firebase_analytics:
```

Comment: Thanks, but seems still lots of packages are not ready for null safety, for example Dio, which is so basic in network routines in Flutter.